# Installing Jupyter Notebook in windows 10 error Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install Jupyter notebook for Python in Windows 10 using the pip command but I am getting an error message saying:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried to change directory to this and typed the pip command in cmd:

```
C:\Users\Praneeth Ravuri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

pip install jupyter
```

I tried installing using the command only but I got the same error.

Comment: I do hope that this isn't another one of those, I've installed python 3.9 and having problems with things which are not yet fully compatible with the new version, type of questions!

Comment: Yes, even I installed Python 3.9.

Comment: Have you tried it using python 3.8 or earlier? Have you got the [latest version](https://github.com/hynek/argon2-cffi/commit/b7463e744907577e43023e019e502e45106728c5) of argon2-cffi.

Comment: Yes, I installed Python 3.8 and now it is working.

Comment: Exactly! There have in the last two weeks or so, been far too many python questions where the issue has been related to updating to 3.9, and it not being compatible with other modules/utilities etc. My general rule of thumb is not to use newer versions of programming/develeopment tools until the dependents which rely upon it, have been tested to ensure the same, or better, compatibility.